# Syncing Database and Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, synchronization

I'm working on a real-time JavaScript Application that requires all changes to a database are mirrored **instantly** in JavaScript and vise versa.

Right now, when changes are made in JavaScript, I make an ajax call to my API and make the corresponding changes to the DOM. On the server, the API handles the request and finishes up by sending a push using PubNub to the other current JavaScript users with the change that has been made. I also include a changeID that is sequential to JavaScript can resync the entire data set if it missed a push. Here is an example of that push:

```
{
    "changeID":"2857693",
    "type":"update",
    "table":"users",
    "where":{ 
        "id":"32"
    },
    "set":{
        "first_name":"Johnny",
        "last_name":"Applesead"
    }
}
```

When JavaScript gets this change, it updates the local storage and makes the corresponding DOM changes based on which table is being changed. **Please keep in mind that my issue is not with updating the DOM, but with syncing the data from the database to JavaScript both quickly and seamlessly.**

Going through this, I can't help but think that this is a terribly complicated solution to something that should be reasonably simple. Am I missing a Gotcha? **How would you sync multiple JavaScript Clients with a MySQL Database seamlessly?**

Comment: "Going through this, I can't help but think that this is a terribly complicated solution to something that should be reasonably simple." – this is wishful thinking. Keeping two data sets, based on **entirely different** low-level models (relational vs. navigational/hierarchical), in sync over a network, is a hard problem with many moving parts involved. Consider that just translating between a database model and an object model "transparently" requires an ORM framework – a complex and invariably leaky abstraction. You're basically looking at implementing (part of) an ORM library in Javascript.

Comment: @millimoose, You have a well thought out and valid point. I guess my sample is as simple as I can get with the obstacles provided. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update the question a few months later - I ended up sticking with this method and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've spent a lot of time working on this exact same problem although for a completely different context. I am creating a Phonegap App and it has to work offline and sync at a later point.

The big revelation for me is that what I really need is a version control between the browser and the server so that's what I made. stores data in `sets` and `keys` within those sets and versions all of those individually. When things go wrong there is a conflict resolution callback that you can use to resolve it.

I just put the project on GitHub, it's URL is https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncIt